# Use sort() or search()?

Tags: python

If I have a file such as below, what would be the best method to print each line that contains the first field in common (ie. print each line that field[0] = 'a', each line that field[0] = 'b')?  Should I use sort(), or populate a dictionary with value as a list, or utilize a class to classify each field, or use search()?  Perhaps I am overcomplicating a simple solution.

The file:

```
a 2012 fff

b 2012 xxx

a 2011 fff

a 2011 vvv

b 2010 sss
```

Regular sort:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        field0,field1,field2=line.split()
        field0.sort() # ???
```

OR

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,field0,field1,field2):
        self.field0=field0
        self.field1=field1
        self.field2=field2
    def grabField():
        for i in MyClass.field0:
            print MyClass.field0,MyClass.field1,MyClass.field2

with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        field0,field1,field2=line.split()
        MyClass(field0,field1,field2)
grabField()
```

I have determined the following code to populate dictionary and sort values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        field0, field1, field2 = line.split()
        res[field0] += [field1, field2]

for i in res.keys():
    print i, sorted(res[i], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

However, this yields "a [2011, 2011, 2012, fff, fff, vvv]" and I want output to be in the exact same format as the input (but sorted):

```
a 2011 fff

a 2011 vvv

a 2012 fff
```

I can't just use sort on the original input since I will be referencing multiple times and need to store in memory.  Should value for each line be stored in a list (ie. dictionary value is list of lists)?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `sorted`:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
...   lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
... 
>>> sorted_nonempty_lines = sorted((l for l in lines if l), key=lambda x: x.split()[0])
>>> 
>>> for line in sorted_nonempty_lines:
...   print line
... 
a 2012 fff
a 2011 fff
a 2011 vvv
b 2012 xxx
b 2010 sss
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're doing. If you want to select all the lines that start with `a`, ignore the rest, and close the file, there's no point in anything more complex than a line-by-line search for lines starting with `a`. You have to go through the whole list once to find all the lines, but then you've got the data you need, so there's no point in doing anything more.

If, on the other hand, you need to query the data multiple times, and you have enough memory to store the while file, it makes sense to use a dict with lists as values, as you suggested. That way, you only have to go through the file once, and can then do multiple queries on the data.

Sorting the data is probably the worst solution for this particular case, because it requires O(n * log(n)) time to sort a list, but only O(n) time to go through the file once and create a dictionary.

Comment: I need to query the data multiple times and include all fields, so my instinct was to utilize a class or dictionary with list value or even a dictionary with value as a class. Just struggling with how to get the data sorted in the output without using sort().

Comment: @Christopher J. Stuart, when you say "sorted in the output," what do you mean? I assume that you understand how to create a dictionary with values that are lists of lines starting with `a` (or whatever). Do you then need those lists to be sorted by another parameter? In that case, you'll have to sort them!

Comment: my apologies, I understand that I should use the first field as the key but I also need the output to be sorted by field[1] (forgot to mention this..sorry!) so that I can say for each key give me all the lines containing that key and sorted based upon field[1]

Comment: @Christopher J. Stuart, ah, well in that case, sorting makes more sense. But I still think the dict-based solution is the best; just use `linedict['a'].sort()` to sort the list whenever it makes sense.

Comment: sorry to keep up the questions, but can I simply use linedict[key].append(field1,field2).sort() to populate the value list?

Comment: @ChristopherJ.Stuart `.append` returns `None`; so that won't work as a one-liner.

Comment: ugh..I suppose I could use a dictionary of dictionaries but that doesn't scale if there are multiple fields that need to be populated in value.

Comment: figured it out...linedict[key].append((field1, field2))